# Why can't I log out users using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Using Rails 4.2 and having the following gems installed.

```
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem "devise_ldap_authenticatable"
```

Everything from what I can tell works fine, except when I click my logout link...

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :data => { :no_turbolink => true } %>
```

It properly redirects the user back to the sign in page on production, but If I refresh that sign_in page I'm sent back to the my root page with a notice message saying "You are already signed in.".  My action for the destroy_user_session_path contains the following:

```
  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
     cookies.delete(:auth_token)
     reset_session
     super
  end
```

When I do the same steps in my development environment everything works fine, but on production I get the behavior I described above.  I also tried, as some posts have recommended, changing the destroy from a `:delete` method to a `:get` (even though this seems very incorrect) but that didn't work.  I also checked that my application.html.erb had the following line in it: `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` -- it does.  And finally here's my (probably too massive) lists of javascript includes...

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery.tokeninput
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete

// for bootstrap 4 add tether below
//= require turbolinks
//= require nprogress
//= require nprogress-turbolinks
//= require nested_form_fields
//= require highcharts
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
//= require highcharts/modules/exporting
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap-multiselect
//= require_tree .
```

If I forgot anything please let me know and I'll include it. Thanks!

**Update (Added destroy action)**

```
  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    cookies.delete(:auth_token)
    reset_session
    super
  end
```

Comment: just call super...let devise do it for you unless needed.

Comment: @Milind, I do call super, sorry I didn't include my destroy action. Updating now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try deleting the entire session not just the auth_token. I'm using same Devise setup above with the exception of devise_ldap_authenticator. Rails 4

```
# app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def destroy
        session.delete(:user_id)
    end
end
```

Then in the view

```
# To log out
<%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => 'delete'%>
```

In my gemfile i'm using active-record session-store:

```
gem 'activerecord-session_store', github: 'rails/activerecord-session_store'
```

And in an initializer

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

Comment: I think the explanation is (and I could be wrong) is if I'm using a :cookie_store for my sessions then I can't destroy or invalidate specific sessions.  The best you can do with :cookie_store is set a timeout to expire the session.  So I've switched to a AR session store as you have explained in your answer.  Thanks!